# Modsecurity Not working with beautified URLs

Tags: nginx, security, mod-security

I have modsecurity on nginx and everything works except for URL like below:

```
https://example.com/input_1.3=6111163&id=1' and 1=1 --
```

But it works for this one:

```
https://example.com?input_1.3=6111163&id=1' and 1=1 --
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: I'd guess the lack of a `?` means there is no start to the query string parameters

Comment: I guess so but this doesn`t mean that there is no security risk. Is there anyway to block them too?